# How does this code optimize minification?

Tags: javascript, minify

I saw some code [here](https://gist.github.com/rma4ok/3371337) that had these variable declarations:

```
var equestAnimationFrame = 'equestAnimationFrame',
    requestAnimationFrame = 'r' + equestAnimationFrame,

    ancelAnimationFrame = 'ancelAnimationFrame',
    cancelAnimationFrame = 'c' + ancelAnimationFrame
```

According to a comment on the page, this is to improve minification, but I couldn't figure out how. Can someone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: I think its because later they use `ancelAnimationFrame`, as in `window[vendor + 'R' + equestAnimationFrame]`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not to improve minification proper - the code in question is a [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) polyfill. This means it's going to try different vendor prefixes. So sometimes the code will be `"requestAnimationFrame"` (lowercase `r`) and sometimes with a vendor prefix such as `msRequestAnimationFrame`.

For this reason it is built dynamically, `"equestAnimationFrame"` is always there but it might be prefixed with an `"r"` or an `"R"`.

The "improve minification" part is because instead of writing:

```
var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                            window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                            window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
```

They run a for loop on `["ms","moz","o", "webkit"]` and try the prefixes. This saves a few bytes at best.

Here is code I believe is clearer and does the same thing:

```
var base = "equestAnimationFrame" // the base string
var alternatives = window["r"+base] || // try the basic option first
['moz', 'ms', 'o', 'webkit'].map(function(x){ 
    return x+"R" + base; // all the options
}).filter(function(x){ // check if in window
    return x in window;
})[0];
```

Comment: In all honesty, I think the "unminified" version is far more readable.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I completely agree. Moreover assuming the code is gzipped and even if it's not - I doubt this would make a significant difference in file size. Sometimes the obvious solution is the better one.

Comment: If you're doing this for loads of properties, then the size saving is going to add up and become significant.

Comment: @Ajedi32 that's like saying unfrozen meat is tastier than frozen meat - of course it is. minified code isn't meant to be readable.